# Is there a PetriNet tool with an IPC interface?

Tags: c++, petri-net

I'm looking for a quality tool to draw PetriNets with that has an interface to connect to my own application. I have a PetriNet abstraction layer, and instantiated a fairly large Net. Now I want to visualize it to ease up the debugging of my software. IPC can be through named pipes, sockets,... I can attach any of that to my code.

I'm currently using the Platform Independent Petrinet Editor. Its a bit messy to use, but it does the job. However, it does not have the above usecase.

This is a list of available tools:
http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/TGI/PetriNets/tools/quick.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take it as a no.

---